# Delete empty rows starting from a column that is not the first

Tags: python, pandas

In pandas I have a df that looks like this:

```
   A      B    C   D
0  a      b     
1  aaa    bbb  cc
2  aa     b    
3  a      b        dd
4              c
```

I'd like to delete all the empty rows, but starting from the "C" cell. So in the example above I'd like to delete only the 0 and 2 row. I don't care if the previous column are empty or not. I'm interested on deleting only the rows that are empty from the "C" column and forward.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Pandas has a function, drop_na, that you can give a subset to (in your case, columns C and D) https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html

I would do the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":["a","aaa","aa","a",None],"B":["b","bbb","b","b", None],"C":[None, "cc", None, None, "c"], "D": [None, None, None, "dd", None]}) # create the test dataframe

df = df.dropna(subset=["C","D"], how="all") # drop rows from the C and D subset if all are null
```

As suggested by comments, if you wanted to make this a function

```
def drop_unwanted(exclude_columns,df): 
    df = df.dropna(subset=[x for x in df.columns if x not in exclude_columns], how="all") 
    return df
```

and give the function the columns you would like to exclude!

Comment: You can do `df.dropna(subset=df.loc[:, 'C':].columns, how="all")` to not rely on column names.

Comment: @SomeDude. Post your comment as answer or edit this post with your suggestion. It's clearly a good enhancement.

Comment: Good ideas! If I were to make this a function I might do more like

def drop_unwanted(exclude_columns):
    df = df.dropna(subset=[x for x in df.columns if x not in exclude_columns], how="all")
    return df

Comment: The comment suggests you use slicing: `subset=df.loc[:, 'C':].columns` instead of `subset=['C', 'D']`

Comment: @ChristinaStebbins OP mentioned to drop rows based on NaNs for column "starting" from "C".

Comment: @Corralien I'd rather prefer this answer to be edited :) But thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, here is one option with [*boolean indexing*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) :

```
out = df[~df.loc[:, "C":].isna().all(axis=1)]
```

Output :

```
print(out)

     A    B    C    D
1  aaa  bbb   cc  NaN
3    a    b  NaN   dd
4  NaN  NaN    c  NaN
```

Comment: Too faster for me! :)

Comment: That was the first thing came up to my head ;)

Comment: I added an option with `drop`

Comment: IMO, @Christina Stebbins's approach is way more better/pandorable.

Comment: Yes I'm agree with that :p

Answer (score 1):

You can slice your dataframe with `loc` and use a boolean mask to select right rows:

```
filtered_df = df[~df.loc[:, 'C':].isna().all(axis=1)]
print(filtered_df)

# Output
      A     B     C     D
1   aaa   bbb    cc  None
3     a     b  None    dd
4  None  None     c  None
```

You can also use `drop`:

```
filtered_df = df.drop(df.loc[:, 'C':].isna().all(axis=1).loc[lambda x: x].index)
print(filtered_df)

# Output
      A     B     C     D
1   aaa   bbb    cc  None
3     a     b  None    dd
4  None  None     c  None
```